# How to pass an anonymous type to a function, then get the values

Tags: c#, dynamic, grouping, anonymous-types

I have a `function` like this:

```
private void DropIncompleteQuarters(//what goes in here? This? IEnumerable<dynamic> gb)
{
    foreach(var groupInGb in gb)
    {
        // What goes in here to get each element?
    }
}
```

I am generating a `Grouping` like this:

```
histData = new List<OHLC>();

var gb = histData.GroupBy(o => new
{
    Year = o.Date.Year,
    Quarter = ((o.Date.Month - 1) / 3) + 1
})
.ToDictionary(g => g.Key, g => g.ToList());
```

I would like to pass `gb` to `DropIncompleteQuarters`, but I am not sure what the `type` should be.

Then inside of `DropIncompleteQuarters`, I would like to iterate over the `items`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I suggest using *named tuple* instead of *anonymous type*. With a slight syntax change - `(...)` instead of `{...}` you can put

```
private void DropIncompleteQuarters(Dictionary<(int Year, int Quarter), 
                                               List<OHLC>> gb)
{
    foreach (var pair in gb)
    {
        // Let's deconstruct pair.Key 
        var (year, quarter) = pair.Key; 
        var list = pair.Value;

        //TODO: some logic for year and quarter and list
    }
}
```

```
histData = new List<OHLC>();

var gb = histData
   .GroupBy(o => ( // change { .. } to ( .. ) and `=` to `:`
      Year    : o.Date.Year,
      Quarter : ((o.Date.Month - 1) / 3) + 1
   ))
   .ToDictionary(g => g.Key, g => g.ToList());
```

Comment: @Ivan: I see; you pass the *entire dictionary* to `DropIncompleteQuarters`; let's change the its signature then. I've edited the answer.